# Sequelize JS - How to handle SQL Server data types that Sequelize doesn't support

Tags: sql-server, sequelize.js

I am working with an existing SQL Server database that cannot be modified, and several tables use datatypes such as

- smallmoney
- bit

Creating a new table is not an option, the existing table must exist as is, however the columns in question (with unsupported datatypes) are never inserted or updated (they are from a legacy requirement that is no longer enforced)... meaning I could fill them with null.

What options do I have to make Sequelize work with these unsupported SQL Server data types?

Comment: One issue I had related to Sequelize pluralizing the table name by default. I had to freeze the model to prevent that... then I was able to read from the table as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Write queries (or views) that convert the values of those columns to types the client supports, or which don't return those columns at all.